# How can I use JavaScript to limit a number between a min/max value?

Tags: javascript, numbers, integer

I want to limit a number between two values, I know that in PHP you can do this:

```
$number = min(max(intval($number), 1), 20);
// this will make $number 1 if it's lower than 1, and 20 if it's higher than 20
```

How can I do this in javascript, without having to write multiple `if` statements and stuff like that? Thanks.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

like this

```
var number = Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(number), 1), 20);
```

#Live Demo:

```js
function limitNumberWithinRange(num, min, max){
  const MIN = min ?? 1;
  const MAX = max ?? 20;
  const parsed = parseInt(num)
  return Math.min(Math.max(parsed, MIN), MAX)
}

alert(
  limitNumberWithinRange(  prompt("enter a number")   )
)
```

Comment: do Javascript has as `intval(num)` function. Cause I know only `parseInt(num)`?

Comment: I dont know about php sorry I edited that I consider it as User defined function

Comment: thanks Joy for telling me about intval in php. and thanks for providing chance to me..

Comment: Don't use `parseInt` unless you know what you are doing, e.g. `parseInt(1e300) === 1`. Just use `Math.min(Math.max(number, 1), 20)`.

Comment: Isn't this backwards? As written, the number is maximum 1, and minimum 20, no?

Comment: @Sandwich Let's pay attention to `Math.max(number, 1)`. It's the maximum value among `number` and `1`. So it's `number` when `number > 1`, and it's `1` when `number <= 1`. i.e. it is always greater than or equals to `1`, no matter what `number` is, as long as `number` is numeric(`Math.max` can return `NaN` when `number` is not numeric.); the **`Math.max` sets the minimum limit** to `1`. And the **`Math.min` sets the maximum limit** to `20` in the same way.

Comment: @Sandwich Remember, `Math.min` and `Math.max` are **not** `Math.setMinimumLimit` and `Math.setMaximumLimit`. Don't be confused.

Comment: You will get unexpected results when running ```limitNumberWithinRange(num, 0, 42)```. In other words: min/max can't be set to 0 with this code.

Comment: I googled this problem because I was having trouble naming my function. `limitNumberWithinRange` is a good name, i'm going to use it 

Answer (score 37):

You have at least two options:

You can use a pair of conditional operators (`? :`):

```
number = number > 100 ? 100 : number < 0 ? 0 : number;
```

Or you can combine `Math.max` and `Math.min`:

```
number = Math.min(100, Math.max(0, number));
```

In both cases, it's relatively easy to confuse yourself, so you might consider having a utility function if you do this in multiple places:

```
function clamp(val, min, max) {
    return val > max ? max : val < min ? min : val;
}
```

Then:

```
number = clamp(number, 0, 100);
```

Answer (score 18):

Use lodash's [`clamp`](https://lodash.com/docs/#clamp) method:

`_.clamp(22, 1, 20) // Outputs 20`

Answer (score 16):

Needs no further explanation:

```
function clamp(value, min, max) {
    return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
}
```

Comment: Would this work for negative numbers aswell such as transform -xdeg?

Comment: @RyanStone what do you mean by "transform -xdeg"? It does work for negative values as well, yes. You can call `clamp(-5, -1, 1)` and it will return `-1`.

Comment: was meaning to use it in Css Transform:rotateX(); which takes in negative values.. Via Javascript

Answer (score 10):

Quote from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39477954/4298200) answer:

> Update for ECMAScript 2017:
>
> `Math.clamp(x, lower, upper)`
>
> But note that as of today, it's a Stage 1 [proposal](https://rwaldron.github.io/proposal-math-extensions/#sec-math.clamp). Until it gets widely supported, you can use a [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ecma-proposal-math-extensions).

Answer (score 2):

### One Liners

```js
const clamp = (num, min, max) => num > max ? max : num < min ? min : num
```

```js
const minmax = (num, min, max) => Math.min(Math.max(num, min), max)
```

### Benchmark

| Browser | `clamp()` | `minmax()` | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chrome | `976,066,844` ops/s | `971,704,488` ops/s | `clamp()` 0.45% faster |
| Firefox | `872,108,437` ops/s | `1,358,476,166` ops/s | `minmax()` 35.8% faster |
| Edge | `958,554,747` ops/s | `936,113,887` ops/s | `clamp()` 2.34% faster |

**JsBench** https://jsbench.me/qhl99e1thl/1

In case of firefox `minmax()` is much faster in compare to others. Though in chrome and Edge `clamp()` is faster than `minmax()` but difference is ignorable. So, my opinion is to use `minmax()` according to the benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.min` and `Math.max`.

Answer (score 1):

I will share my robust function to enforce **whole numbers** (because of the `integer` tag), it has features like optional min/max parameters and `-0` protection:

```
function toInt(val, min, max){
    val=(val*1 || 0);
    val=(val<0 ? Math.ceil(val) : Math.floor(val));

    min*=1;
    max*=1;

    min=((Number.isNaN(min) ? -Infinity : min) || 0);
    max=((Number.isNaN(max) ? Infinity : max) || 0);

    return Math.min(Math.max(val, min), max);
}
```

Some quick notes:

- The `(... || 0)` behind the scenes is dealing with `-0` to change it to `0`, which is almost always what you want.
- The `min` and `max` parameters are optional. When blank or invalid values are passed, they will turn into `-Infinity` and `Infinity` so they silently don't interfere with `Math.min()` and `Math.max()`.
- You can change `Number.isNaN(x)` ECMAScript-6 to `x!==x` (results in true only for `NaN`) for more compatibility with *really* old browsers, but this is simply not necessarily anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily just extend `Math` by adding your own method...

ES6

```
Math.minmax = (value, min, max) => Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
```

ES5

```
Math.minmax = function(value, min, max){
    return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
}
```

Comment: PLEASE do not do this. extending built-in objects in this way credibly damages the standardization process. Just use a function.