# How to check if a number is between two values?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I'm telling the browser to do something if the window size is greater than 500px. I do it like so:

```
if (windowsize > 500) {
    // do this
}
```

This works great, but I would like to apply this same method, but with a range of numbers. So I would like to tell my browser to do stuff if the window size is between 500px and 600px. I know this wouldn't work, but here is how I imagined it:

```
if (windowsize > 500-600) {
    // do this
}
```

Is this even possible, within JavaScript?

Comment: Surely the more correct check would be if ( windowsize >= 500 && windowsize <= 600 )  or if ( !(windowsize < 500 || windowsize > 600) )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a value is within a range of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454198/check-if-a-value-is-within-a-range-of-numbers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the most elegant way to cap a number to a segment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409895/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-cap-a-number-to-a-segment)

Answer (score 301, accepted):

Tests whether `windowsize` is greater than `500` and lesser than `600` meaning that neither values `500` or `600` itself will result in the condition becoming true.

```
if (windowsize > 500 && windowsize < 600) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks undefined, just to confirm this will do what I want within the browser when the window size is greater then 500px and less than 600px, essentially functioning within the range of 500-600px only, correct? (I'm not too good with this stuff lol)

Comment: @Dyck Yes, it does so :), note that jQuery is only a JavaScript library.

Comment: Mind that this condition is only true when `windowsize` is at least 501px and at most 599px. **500px and 600px are excluded.** Add equality to comparisons if you want inclusive of these values.

Comment: Just a detail, but is more readable the following way: `if(500 < windowsize && windowsize < 600)`

Answer (score 152):

I had a moment, so, although you've already accepted an answer, I thought I'd contribute the following:

```js
Number.prototype.between = function(a, b) {
  var min = Math.min(a, b),
    max = Math.max(a, b);

  return this > min && this < max;
};

var windowSize = 550;

console.log(windowSize.between(500, 600));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6P2q4/39).

Or, if you'd prefer to have the option to check a number is in the defined range *including the end-points*:

```js
Number.prototype.between = function(a, b, inclusive) {
  var min = Math.min(a, b),
    max = Math.max(a, b);

  return inclusive ? this >= min && this <= max : this > min && this < max;
}

var windowSize = 500;

console.log(windowSize.between(500, 603, true));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6P2q4/40).

References:

- [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max).
- [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min).

Comment: Nice solution. Just nitpicking here, but would instead prefer `return min < this && this < max` as it feels more correct, seeing as `this` is sandwiched between the comparison operators.

Comment: it's MUCH better to create a function that doesn't modify the `Number` object. This is an anti-pattern and will come and bite you if ECMA standards change to include a `Number.between()` function, or if another library or another piece of code defines `Number.prototype.between` elsewhere with a different definition. Instead, make a helper function and use that!

Comment: @MonarchWadia While your point makes sense that modifying/extending native objects is bad practice, I feel it's a bit redundant having this preached everywhere (no offense). I can't count the times I've seen "don't modify native objects". For me, this is like someone selling household knives warning the buyer about the possible dangers of the knife every single time he/she sells one like its the seller's responsibility if there's any harm. The dangers should be common knowledge. It should be up to the user if he/she ignores them or not.

Comment: Why would you want to do all of that?

Comment: @akinuri uff it's not just me then that's sick of those copy-pasta everywhere. I can't imagine how many comments like that I would get if I create am extending prototype + RegEx answer on this site lol

Answer (score 118):

I prefer to put the variable on the inside to give an extra hint that the code is validating my variable is between a range values

```
if (500 < size && size < 600) { doStuff(); }
```

Comment: This is my preference, since it's closer to python's `min < testval < max` syntax

Answer (score 38):

It's an old question, however might be useful for someone like me.

`lodash` has `_.inRange()` function https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#inRange

Example:

```
_.inRange(3, 2, 4);
// => true
```

Please note that this method utilizes the `Lodash` utility library, and requires access to an installed version of Lodash.

Comment: Please be aware than the end value is not included. eg. `_.inRange(10, 0, 10) // => false`

Comment: As the OP limited the question scope to `Javascript`, it's worth noting that this method utilizes the `Lodash` utility library, and requires access to an installed version of Lodash.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it simply

```
if (windowsize > 500 && windowsize < 600) {
//your logic
}
```

Or if you want **clean code** You can write your own function in your main js file of any common place.

```
Number.prototype.between = function(a, b) {
 var min = Math.min.apply(Math, [a, b]),
    max = Math.max.apply(Math, [a, b]);
  return this > min && this < max;
};
```

Then you can call it like this

```
if(windowsize.between(500, 600)){
 //your logic
}
```

Comment: Both solutions are exactly the same as presented in other answers.

Answer (score 6):

I know there's an accepted answer, but I want to provide some ways that can be useful in certain scenarios. If we want to check whether `n` is between `x` and `y`, we can do:

```
x <= n && n <= y
(x - n) * (y - n) <= 0
```

The second one is very useful when you're trying to get the same result even if you swap `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 5):

this is a generic method, you can use everywhere

```
const isBetween = (num1,num2,value) => value > num1 && value < num2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Multiple clause in `if` condition instead of writing

```
if (windowsize > 500-600) {
    // do this
}
```

because this really makes no sense
logically JavaScript will read your if condition like

```
windowSize > -100
```

because it calculates `500-600` to `-100`

You should use `&&` for strict checking both cases for example which will look like this

```
if( windowSize > 500 && windowSize < 600 ){

// Then doo something

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the shortest method possible:

```
if (Math.abs(v-550)<50) console.log('short')
if ((v-500)*(v-600)<0) console.log('short')
```

Parametrized:

```
if (Math.abs(v-max+v-min)<max+min) console.log('short')
if ((v-min)*(v-max)<0) console.log('short')
```

You can divide both sides by 2 if you don't understand how the first one works;)

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented this bit of jQuery to show and hide bootstrap modal values. Different fields are displayed based on the value range of a users textbox entry.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.noConflict();
    var Ammount = document.getElementById('Ammount');

    $("#addtocart").click(function () {

            if ($(Ammount).val() >= 250 && $(Ammount).val() <= 499) {
                {
                    $('#myModal').modal();
                    $("#myModalLabelbronze").show();
                    $("#myModalLabelsilver").hide();
                    $("#myModalLabelgold").hide();
                    $("#myModalPbronze").show();
                    $("#myModalPSilver").hide();
                    $("#myModalPGold").hide();
                }
            }
    });
```

Comment: Using jQuery for trivial functions was in 2013 maybe an option but isn't today

Comment: True but I am afraid people will still use it today

Comment: Out of curiosity: why is jQuery worse to use for trivial functions now than then?

Comment: @Julix mostly performance, albeit negligible in this case. The general point would be "don't use jQuery when it is not necessary" but these comments are not the place to (re)start the debate. have fun with this though :) http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif

Comment: This is just an implementation of the solution. OP already has access to the values. So jQuery `$().val()` is irrelevant and not necessary. But again, in the original version of the question, OP mentions jQuery, for a simple arithmetic check. (sigh) That's the first mistake.

Answer (score 0):

just like David answer but i needed inclusive for either a or b. so my sol:

```js
export const between = (num: number, a: number, b: number, inclusiveA = true, inclusiveB = true): boolean => {
  if (a > b) [a, b, inclusiveA, inclusiveB] = [b, a, inclusiveB, inclusiveA];
  if (a == b && (inclusiveA || inclusiveB)) [inclusiveA, inclusiveB] = [true, true];
  return (inclusiveA ? num >= a : num > a) && (inclusiveB ? num <= b : num < b);
};

if (require.main === module) {
  console.log(between(12, 15, 10)); //true
  console.log(between(15, 15, 10)); //true
  console.log(between(15, 10, 15)); //true
  console.log(between(10, 10, 15, false)); //false
  console.log(between(15, 10, 10, true, false)); //false
  
  //edge case: if a==b then enough that either of the edges is inclusive
  console.log(between(10, 10, 10, true, false)); //true
}
```

its also typescript and not javascript

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function handleBetween(number, calc) {
        let [a, b] = calc;
        let min = Math.min(a, b), max = Math.max(a, b);
        return number > min && number < max;
    }

    if(510 >500 && 510 <600){
    console.log(`510 >500 && 510 <600 is true`)
    }


    if(610 >500 && 610 <600){
    // false
    console.log(`610 >500 && 610 <600 is true`)
    } else console.log(`610 >500 && 610 <600 is false`)


    
     console.log(handleBetween(510, [500, 600])); // true
     console.log(handleBetween(610, [500, 600])); // false
```