# Write conditional statement for a range (3 < x < 9)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

How should I write an if statement which is true only for a given range e.g. return true for x if (3 < x < 9) ?

```
if ((myNum > 3) || (myNum < 9))
{ 
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "<button>Hello World</button>";
}
```

Comment: You want to use && not ||

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if a number is between two values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718561/check-if-a-number-is-between-two-values)

Comment: using || means 'or' which means either condition can be true to return true. Basically, any number you use will return true in your current setup.

Comment: I'm going to leave this open (not close it) because the choice of duplicates is so poor. The duplicate is so poor because (1) it has 0 votes (it is not deemed a "good" question); and (2) it was closed as "lacks minimal understanding". However, Stack Overflow welcomes less experienced programming enthusiasts, so folks like Thomas should get an answer. Also see [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use correct operator `||` is `OR` operator, use `AND` operator `&&`

```
if ((myNum > 3) && (myNum < 9))
{ 
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "<button>Hello World</button>";
}
```

Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

AND not OR

```
if (myNum > 3 && myNum < 9) { 
  document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "<button>Hello World</button>";
}
```