# How to search a range in html table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table structure like this:

```
City |    %age   | Year 
NY   | 57% - 95% | 2011
NY   | 30% - 65% | 2012
FL   | 50% - 60% | 2012
AL   | 10% - 50% | 2014
```

I am able to search in the text using this code:

```
jQuery('#tblSearch tr td.td5:containsNoCase(\'' + jQuery('#txtSearch').val() + '\')').parent().show();

jQuery.expr[":"].containsNoCase = function (el, i, m) {
    var search = m[3];
    if (!search)
    return false;
    return eval("/" + search + "/i").test($(el).text());
};
```

But I do not have any idea how can I search ranges like if user want to search for 60% then How can I get first three result?

Thanks in advance! 
Please refer if possible duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: How do you create that result? PHP? Why don't you add some `data-*` attribute to your elements like `<td data-agemin="57" data-agemax="95">57% - 95%</td>`? Than you can easily filter your elements by `data-attribute`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I am not using any php just html and jquery with table.

Comment: Okay Let me do this I didnt think about it! Thanks @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: Yes table is manually created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rolled a number checker

```
jQuery.expr[":"].withinNum = function (el, i, m, num) {
    str = $(el).text();
    var min = parseInt(str, 10),
        max = parseInt(str.substr(-4), 10);
    return m[3] >= min && m[3] <= max;
};
```

You can use it like this:

```
$("li:withinNum(50)").addClass('bold');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n8nu6mo4/3/

---

Also available as a one-liner:

```
jQuery.expr[":"].withinNum = function(el, i, m, num){ str = $(el).text(); return m[3] >= parseInt(str, 10) && m[3] <= parseInt(str.substr(-4), 10); };
```

---

### Update: target the Table Row

*See @Roko's comments*

```
jQuery.expr[":"].withinNum = function (el, i, m) {
    var v = $(el).text().match(/\d+/g)||'';
    return m[3] >= +v[0] && m[3] <= +v[1];
};
```

use like: (*remove `.closest("tr")` to target only the TD elements*)

```
$("td:withinNum(50)").closest("tr").addClass('gold');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n8nu6mo4/9/

Also available as a one-liner:

```
jQuery.expr[":"].withinNum=function(e,i,m){var v=$(e).text().match(/\d+/g)||'';return m[3]>=+v[0]&&m[3]<=+v[1];};
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Fixed. Thanks for the bug report.

Comment: Good edit but now will simply fail if we remove a whitespace: http://jsfiddle.net/n8nu6mo4/4/ you should use `.match` and the resulting Array like I did. Bulletproof.

Comment: Added an example that uses TABLE (per-OP's-request) and a fix that prevents `null||undefined` issues: http://jsfiddle.net/n8nu6mo4/7/

Comment: @Roko: I know, but I was only tidying up, not re-writing the answer entirely. Had I written it entirely from scratch, though, I would've gone with `String.match()`, and probably used a previous answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18881828/82548) for the range-check.

Comment: I created this fiddle I am trying to do search by combination of inputs here: http://jsfiddle.net/1mw86231/7/

Comment: Great I Marked your answer as accepted But I am try to do something more.

Answer (score 3):

- jQuery `filter()` method will help you here.
- First you need to select all `TR` elements that have TD (cause some can have `TH`),
- than inside the filter function you need to extract the MIN and MAX values from the text using simply `.match(/\d+/g)` which returns something like: `val === ["57", "95"]`. Being strings you can convert easily to numbers using the `unary +` operator: `+val[0]`.
- the `.filter()`'s `return`, after checking your input value is in range `+val[0]<=v && +val[1]>v` will than **toggleClass** the matching TR selectors.

```js
var TR = $("#table").find("tr:has(td)");

function filterTable() {
  var v = +this.value; // The input value
  TR.filter(function(){
    var val = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text().match(/\d+/g);
    return $(this).toggleClass("select", +val[0]<=v && +val[1]>v);
  });
}

$("#range").on("input", filterTable);
```

```css
table td{border:1px solid #777;}
.select{background:gold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id=table>
<tr><th>City </th><th>    %Age   </th><th> Year </th></tr>
<tr><td>NY   </td><td> 57% - 95% </td><td> 2011</td></tr>
<tr><td>NY   </td><td> 30% - 65% </td><td> 2012</td></tr>
<tr><td>FL   </td><td> 50% - 60% </td><td> 2012</td></tr>
<tr><td>AL   </td><td> 10% - 50% </td><td> 2014</td></tr>
</table>
  
Range: <input id=range type=number value=100 maxlength=3>%
```

Answer (score 2):

This shows all that value is within the range and hides others

```
function filterByPercentVal(val) {
    $('tbody tr').show().filter(function () {
        var rangeText = $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(1).text()).replace(/%|\s/g, ''),
            rangeLimits = rangeText.split('-');
        return !(val>= parseInt(rangeLimits[0], 10) && val<= parseInt(rangeLimits[1], 10));

    }).hide();
}
/* usage */
filterByPercentVal(55);
```

Uses table as markup, subsequent calls make it reusable without any changes

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rcgqmkyb/1)**</kbd>