# Java Script, Need help finding my error

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var score = prompt("Enter your score. Grade must be between 100-0.");

 if ( score>==90 ) 
    {
        document.write ( "Your grade is an A." )
    }
else if ( score <89>==80 )
    {
        document.write ( "Your grade is a B." )
    }
else if ( score <79>==70 )
    {
        document.write ( "Your grade is a C.")
    }
else if ( score <69>==60 ) 
    {
        document.write ( "Your grade is a D.")
    }
else if ( score <59>==0 )
    {
        document.write ( "Your grade is a F")
   }

}//end if
</script>
```

Comment: What error?  What are you haveing trouble with?

Comment: Your `if` statements are not valid. To check whether a value is between 2 other values, you should use [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14718577/1913729). However, in your case, I believe [this will be enough](https://jsfiddle.net/gyq2296p/).

Comment: You tagged this as Java, and didn't post what exactly you have a problem with

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here are some guidelines to asking good questions for future reference. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  For starters, you should do some research. A quick google search of javascript if statements should reveal you're using invalid operators and that you can use `&&` for checking multiple conditions. Assuming you don't find this information however, you should try to ask your question in the form of a question. "I'm trying to assign a grade based on score, but I can't get it to work. I try to run, and here's what happens. Here's my code, how do i fix this?"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should be

```
if ( score>==90 ) 
 {
    document.write ( "Your grade is an A." )
 }
else if ( score >==80 )
{
    document.write ( "Your grade is a B." )
} 
else if ( score >==70 )
{
    document.write ( "Your grade is a C.")
}
else if ( score >==60 ) 
 {
    document.write ( "Your grade is a D.")
 }
else if ( score >==0 )
{
    document.write ( "Your grade is a F")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Java**Script** question but you need to learn about the "and" operator.  You really want each "else" to be something like:

```
else if ( score <= 89 && score >= 80 )
```

for all of the "else if" statements.  That could really be simplified if you just have the second part, i.e.

```
else if ( score >= 80 )
```

since you already checked for 90 and above previously.

EDIT - and I was beaten to my edit - you can't use the <== or >== operators.

Comment: `<==` and `>==` are not valid and will cause an error. It should be `>=` or `<=`

Comment: Please don't answer these garbage questions. You're continuing a bad precedent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, since you didn't ask a question, but I'm guessing it's this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var score = prompt("Enter your score. Grade must be between 100-0.");

    if ( score >== 90 ) 
    {
        document.write ( "Your grade is an A." )
    }
    else if ( score >== 80 )
    {
        document.write ( "Your grade is a B." )
    }
    else if ( score >==70 )
    {
        document.write ( "Your grade is a C.")
    }
    else if ( score >==60 ) 
    {
        document.write ( "Your grade is a D.")
    }
    else if ( score >== 0 )
    {
        document.write ( "Your grade is a F")
    }

}//end if
</script>
```

You might want to read up on [if statements in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp).  Usually you put one condition that evaluates to true or false, such as `thing a` >== `thing b`.