# My IF-ELSE Statement is always returning the first value in Google Appscript. Tried debugging everywhere

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to automatically create Google docs by looking at my student scores. I have an if statement that checks the score, assigns a value and a function that prints the same. Everything seems to work, except that my if statement always returns the first value. How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```js
function createPdf() {
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Summary');
  const lastRow = ws.getLastRow();
  const score = ws.getRange(lastRow, 3).getValue();
  const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById('test1');

  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);

  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  const paragraph = body.getParagraphs();
  body.replaceText('{percentage}', percentage);
  body.replaceText('{score}', score);
  if (50.0 < score < 120.0) {
    paragraph[13].appendText('POOR') && paragraph[17].appendText('xyz.');
  } else if (score >= 120.0) {
    paragraph[13].appendText('GOOD') && paragraph[17].appendText('abc.');
  } else {
    paragraph[13].appendText('VERY POOR') && paragraph[17].appendText('ouy.');
  }

  openDoc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Comment: `if ( (50.0 < score) && (score < 120.0) )`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a value is within a range of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454198/check-if-a-value-is-within-a-range-of-numbers) or [How to check if a number is between two values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718561/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-between-two-values)

Comment: What do you mean by "my if statement always return the first value"? Can you add sample data to your question to illustrate the exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

You approach is always `true`, bcause the first part

```
50.0 < score
```

is either `true` or `false`. For the next comparison with the boolean value

```
boolean < 120.0
```

the bolean value is converted to number `0` or `1` and this value is always smaller than `120`.

To overcome this you need two comparisons with [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND).

```
50.0 < score && score < 120.0
```

Answer (score -1):

If we use `3 > 2 > 1` as an example.

From left to right `3 > 2` is `true`. `true = 1` & `false = 0`

`2 > 1` becomes `1 > 1`, which is trivially `false`.

Hence,
if `50 < score` is true, then `50 < score = 1`. Thereby the evaluation is equivalent to `1 < 120.0` which is always `true`.

Comment: To improve the quality if your answer, you need to refer to JS coercion which is in play here.