# Else-if Block not executing

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The last `else` `if` block is not getting executed when the condition is satisfied please help. Thank you.

```js
let rotatingArr = (n, arr, k) => {
  if (n == arr.length && k !== 0 && k <= arr.length) {
    let arr2 = []
    arr
    let delItems = Math.abs(arr.length - k)
    console.log(delItems)
    let modArr = arr.slice().splice(delItems)
    modArr
    arr.splice(-k)
    console.log(arr)
    let result = [...modArr, ...arr];
    return result
  } else if (k == 0) {
    return arr;
  } else if (11 > k > arr.length) {
    k = k - 5
    arr
    let delItems = Math.abs(arr.length - k)
    console.log(delItems)
    let modArr = arr.slice().splice(delItems)
    modArr
    arr.splice(-k)
    console.log(arr)
    let result = [...modArr, ...arr];
    return result
  }
}

console.log(rotatingArr(5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 10))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a number is between two values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718561/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-between-two-values)

Comment: What exactly is this function supposed to do? Hopefully more than just rotating the input array ;-) Now seriously, this is a pretty confusing pile of code and there must be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not support that kind of infix operators. Your code is executing `(11 > k) > array.length`.

Answer (score 1):

The [relational operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#relational_operators) (e.g. `>`) evaluate two values to a boolean.

Therefore, your condition `11 > k > arr.length` will be evaluated in two steps:

1. `11 > k`: This will evaluate to either true or false.
2. `(11 > k) > arr.length`: This will compare the boolean of the previous expression with `arr.length`. Because `true == 1` and `false == 0`, this expression will always evaluate to false for `arr.length > 1`.

You should do these comparisons (`11 > k` and `k > arr.length`) in two distinct comparisons, and combine them with a [logical operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#binary_logical_operators).