# How to set a min/max value for variable increasing/decreasing with scrollTop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable called `yPos` increasing and decreasing based on the value of `$(window).scrollTop()` on scroll. I would like to set a maximum and minimum value so that the `yPos` variable cannot be any lower than the min value and cannot be bigger than the max value, but still change depending on `scrollTop`. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: what have you tried ? where is the code that changes yPos ?

Comment: Does [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409895/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-cap-a-number-to-a-segment) answers your question?

Comment: Do you want to block the user to a certain scroll area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const max = yourMax;
const min = yourMin;

let yPos = $(window).scrollTop();

if(yPos > max) {
  yPos = max;
}
else if(yPos < min) {
  yPos = min;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this.

```
var yPos= 0;
var min_value = 10;
var max_value = 100;
if($(window).scrollTop() >= min_value && $(window).scrollTop()<= max_value)
{
  yPos = $(window).scrollTop();
}
```

**note**: *this just a logic, please don't copy paste this to your code.*

Comment: why it is not working ? this is just a logic only how to do it and not the complete answer with fiddle or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var scroll = 0;; 
  var maxvalue = 100;
  var minvalue = 10;
  var temp = 0;
  $(document).scroll(function(){  
    temp = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(temp > maxvalue)
    {
     temp = maxvalue;      
    }
    if(temp < minvalue){
      temp = minvalue;
    }
    scroll = temp;
   
        
     
    console.log(scroll);
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  height:200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```