# How to get closest floating point number that is less/greater than a given number

Tags: javascript

Here is a sample function:

```
function step(x, min, max) {
  return x >= min && x <= max ? x : 0;
}

console.log(step(-3 - Number.EPSILON, -3, 5)); // Expected 0, actual -3
console.log(step(5 + Number.EPSILON, -3, 5)); // Expected 0, actual 5
```

I need to check, that it returns zero for values outside [min, max] interval. For sure I can subtract/add a bigger number, for example 1. But I'm pretty sure, that there should exist a function returning previous/next floating point number. Could you please suggest the function or how to implement it?

Comment: *"But I'm pretty sure, that there should exist a function returning previous/next floating point number."* What makes you think that? It would almost certainly be on [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) if so, and there isn't one there, so...

Comment: I don't understand your code. What is the given number in your code?

Comment: Why is this function called `step`? I think I'm missing something...

Comment: Would clamp cut it together with `Math.round()`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409895/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-cap-a-number-to-a-segment

Comment: @T.J.Crowder https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function

Comment: Your code is not the step function. The step function doesn't return `0` or `x`. It returns a rounded `x`. Why do you need the next floating point in a step function?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Remembered, I saw this function in other languages, for example in Java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextAfter-double-double- I was sure that JavaScript has such a function too, but it seems I'm wrong

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not all adjacent representable numbers are the same mathematical distance from one another. Floating point arcana isn't my strong suit, but if you want to find the next representable number, I think you need to keep increasing what you add/subtract from it by `Number.EPSILON` for as long as you keep getting the same number.

The **very naive, simplistic** approach would look like this (but keep reading):

```js
// DON'T USE THIS
function next(x) {
    const ep = x < 0 ? -Number.EPSILON : Number.EPSILON;
    let adder = ep;
    let result;
    do {
        result = x + adder;
        adder += ep;
    } while (result === x);
    return result;
}

console.log(`Next for -3: ${next(-3)}`);
console.log(`Next for 5: ${next(5)}`);
```

(That's assuming direction based on the sign of the number given, which is probably not what you really want, but is easily switched up.)

**But**, that would take **hours** (at least) to handle `next(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)`.

When I posted my caveat on the above originally, I said a better approach would take the magnitude of `x` into account *"...or do bit twiddling (which definitely takes us into floating point arcana land)..."* and you pointed to Java's `Math.nextAfter` operation, so I had to find out what they do. And indeed, it's bit twiddling, and it's wonderfully simple. Here's a re-implementation of the OpenJDK's version from [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#L2822) (the line number in that link will rot):

```js
// A JavaScript implementation of OpenJDK's `Double.nextAfter` method.
function nextAfter(start, direction) {
    // These arrays share their underlying memory, letting us use them to do what
    // Java's `Double.doubleToRawLongBits` and `Double.longBitsToDouble` do.
    const f64 = new Float64Array(1);
    const b64 = new BigInt64Array(f64.buffer);

    // Comments from https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java:

    /*
     * The cases:
     *
     * nextAfter(+infinity, 0)  == MAX_VALUE
     * nextAfter(+infinity, +infinity)  == +infinity
     * nextAfter(-infinity, 0)  == -MAX_VALUE
     * nextAfter(-infinity, -infinity)  == -infinity
     *
     * are naturally handled without any additional testing
     */

    /*
     * IEEE 754 floating-point numbers are lexicographically
     * ordered if treated as signed-magnitude integers.
     * Since Java's integers are two's complement,
     * incrementing the two's complement representation of a
     * logically negative floating-point value *decrements*
     * the signed-magnitude representation. Therefore, when
     * the integer representation of a floating-point value
     * is negative, the adjustment to the representation is in
     * the opposite direction from what would initially be expected.
     */

    // Branch to descending case first as it is more costly than ascending
    // case due to start != 0.0d conditional.
    if (start > direction) {
        // descending
        if (start !== 0) {
            f64[0] = start;
            const transducer = b64[0];
            b64[0] = transducer + (transducer > 0n ? -1n : 1n);
            return f64[0];
        } else {
            // start == 0.0d && direction < 0.0d
            return -Number.MIN_VALUE;
        }
    } else if (start < direction) {
        // ascending
        // Add +0.0 to get rid of a -0.0 (+0.0 + -0.0 => +0.0)
        // then bitwise convert start to integer.
        f64[0] = start + 0;
        const transducer = b64[0];
        b64[0] = transducer + (transducer >= 0n ? 1n : -1n);
        return f64[0];
    } else if (start == direction) {
        return direction;
    } else {
        // isNaN(start) || isNaN(direction)
        return start + direction;
    }
}

function test(start, direction) {
    const result = nextAfter(start, direction);
    console.log(`${start} ${direction > 0 ? "up" : "down"} is ${result}`);
}

test(-3, -Infinity);
test(5, Infinity);
test(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, Infinity);
test(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2, Infinity);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The simple fix for big scales is to use the follwoing increment `const ep = x * Number.EPSILON` or maybe `const ep = x * Number.EPSILON / 1000` However it doesn't guarantee that the increment is smallest possible. It seems that Java and C++ implementations converts a number to a binnary representation and adds 1 to the lowerest bit. But I guess it's not trivial to implement in JavaScript.

Comment: @Denis - If it were **always** adding 1 to the lowest bit, that would be fairly easy to implement in JavaScript, but I think it's much more complicated than that in reality, because of how the format works. (I could be wrong, though.) Now I'm curious and looking at Java's `nextAfter`... :-)

Comment: @Denis - I just had to look to see how it worked, The OpenJDK's source shows it really is very nearly as simple as adding one to the 64-bit two's complement interpretation of the double's bits. I've updated the answer with the implementation.

Comment: It's really cool! Thanks!