# Resizable Sidebar : How to set the maximum width of the main area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a layout in which the sidebar is resizable. I have done that using Javascript. But I want it to have a maximum and minimum value of resize. I have done that for the sidebar part by setting the max-width and min-width for the sidebar. But the problem is that main area goes decreasing(when expanding) even though the sidebar has been limited using max-width. I have been adding margin-left property to the main area according to the cursor pointer movement (using js ). But there is no property which allows us to set the maximum or minimum margin-left. How can I achieve this. Can anybody suggest any workaround to this ?

Js Fiddle - The whole code - https://jsfiddle.net/pdo4yjmg/

Please try to expand above 400px in the fiddle result , you can see the problem there ( 400px is the max-width )

Js part -

```
var element = document.getElementById('resizable');
  if (element) {
    var resizer = document.createElement('div');
    resizer.className = 'draghandle';
    resizer.style.width = '6px';
    resizer.style.height = '100vh';
    element.appendChild(resizer);
    resizer.addEventListener('mousedown', initResize, false);
  }

  function initResize(e) {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', Resize, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', stopResize, false);
    document.getElementById("mainArea").classList.add('marginLeft')
  }

  function Resize(e) {
    element.style.width = (e.clientX - element.offsetLeft) + 'px';
    document.getElementById("mainArea").style.marginLeft = (e.clientX - element.offsetLeft) + 'px';
  }

  function stopResize(e) {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', Resize, false);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopResize, false);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have successfully constrained the sidebar to a `min-width` of `200` and `max-width` of `400`, I would suggest you do the same with your `margin-left`. **But there is no such property in CSS that allows for limiting the margin**, ***you would need to resort to JavaScript***. Perhaps where you set the `margin-left` of mainArea, ensure your new value is between 200 and 400:

```
document.getElementById("mainArea").style.marginLeft = Math.min(Math.max(parseInt((e.clientX - element.offsetLeft)), 200), 400) + 'px';
```

Also, see [How can I use JavaScript to limit a number between a min/max value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842747/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-limit-a-number-between-a-min-max-value)

Answer (score 1):

Complete resizable:

```js
  function Resize(e) {
    element.style.width = (e.clientX - element.offsetLeft) + 'px';
    if(parseInt(element.style.width) <- 200)
        lement.style.width = '200px'
    document.getElementById("mainArea").style.marginLeft = (e.clientX - element.offsetLeft) + 'px';
  }
```